# how to get sum of two arrays with same key in foreach

Tags: php

how can i get the sum of two array with same key? if i am right. My goal here is to get the total hours from two arrays, And how can i make this foreached array jump into the next value of the array if it.

I have this foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach($unique_date as $unique_dates){

}?>
```

Aaaand below the foreach there's this code(because i want to see the arrays):

```
<?php $arrayName = array(
                     'unique' => $unique_date
                    );
var_dump($arrayName);
 ?>
```

the result was this:

```
array (size=1)
  'unique' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=9)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'emp_id' => string '600064' (length=6)
          'dtr_date' => string '2015-05-01' (length=10)
          'dtr_time' => string '276200' (length=6)
          'timediffs' => string '09:18:00' (length=8)
          'status' => string 'in' (length=2)
          'emp_fname' => string 'Jim' (length=3)
          'emp_mname' => string 'Ramos' (length=5)
          'emp_lname' => string 'Salem' (length=5)
      1 => 
        array (size=9)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'emp_id' => string '600064' (length=6)
          'dtr_date' => string '2015-05-04' (length=10)
          'dtr_time' => string '256000' (length=6)
          'timediffs' => string '11:00:00' (length=8)
          'status' => string 'In' (length=2)
          'emp_fname' => string 'Jim' (length=3)
          'emp_mname' => string 'Ramos' (length=5)
          'emp_lname' => string 'Salem' (length=5)
```

what i want was something like this:
for example:
 $time1 = $unique_dates['timediffs'](which suppose to have the value of '09:18:00') and
$time2 = $unique_dates['timediffs'](which also suppose to have the value of '11:00:00')

i want to add the two variables $result = $time1+$time2;

but i dont know how because what i always get was the value of $time1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (not tested)

```
$one=$whateveryoucallit['unique'][0];
$two=$whateveryoucallit['unique'][1];
```

This will get you each array in one variable, so you can do:

```
$time1 = $one['dtr_date']." ".$one['timediffs'];
$time2 = $two['dtr_date']." ".$two['timediffs'];
$result = strtotime($time1) + strtotime($time2);
```

then you can

```
echo date('y-m-d', $result);
```

Comment: sorry it didn't work but here i tried this echo $unique_dates['timediffs'] i got both ' 09:18:00 11:00:00 '. how to sum these hours and mins?

Comment: You need to use strtotime, read the manual about "php strtotime" ... it converts an "English" date string into unix time stamp. After that you use the "date()" function to convert it back.

Comment: okay, but after that how can i add 09:18:00 and 11:00:00 if they came from different array?